# Is displaying comments disabled?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I can't seem to be able to see/display any comments on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions

Is this a setting I can change, a feature or a bug?

--EDIT--

When looking at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) question it says **add / show 5 more comments**

Clicking that link causes it to disapear, but the comments don't show up, as they would on StackOverflow.

Comment: Indeed a bug, comments under the fold are not showing for me either.

Comment: Just encountered it myself on the main site (but not here).

Comment: Closed as the "community user" keeps promoting this to the top of the site, but the bug was fixed ages ago.

Comment: @Andrew: IIUC, the Community♦ does that for questions that count as unanswered, so voting up an answer stops it.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping/11671#11671

Comment: @Charles: true, but in this case I didn't think that either of the answers actually warranted voting up!  Not that it really matters (as we're on meta), but if Geoff had answered saying "Sorry about that, we've fixed the bug" then I'd've voted for that and left it.  But as this question _did_ only refer to a specific instance, I felt that closing as "too localised" would be an acceptable way of removing it from the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean on the listing of all questions?  If so, that's by design.  You only see a bit of each question there and have to click on the question itself to see any more information.

Comment: I'll edit my question to clarify!

Comment: strange, I can see the comment here (since it's below some limit possibly?)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly question. I am unable to find the comment link on any question or answer other than my own answers, even if I click on the question and go to the respective long version of the page.

Comment: You need 50 reputation to be able to add comments (except for your own questions). See the reputation requirements in the faq: http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: You should have asked this as a new question on the meta site. A question like this might be helpful for new people arriving here :)

Comment: @Julian: Well, it's also in the FAQ. I'm not sure it's any more likely that someone will read other questions than that they'll read the FAQ.