# User Table scrambled?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm writing this message under the alias of 'qbi', but that is not my name and not my alias, but the ID that I get shown when I visit meta.tex.stackexchange.com (due to a cookie, I assume).

I registered on meta.tex.stackexchange.com some days ago under the alias of 'lexu' and even posted a question: [Is displaying comments disabled?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/is-displaying-comments-disabled), that is now associated to the 'qbi' alias, but an 'answer posted' email was sent to my email account. The original 'lexu' alias on meta.tex... is gone, but still exists on tex.stackexchange.

Did anyone else see similar 'confusion'?

I don't assume any wrong doing on anyones part, btw, I'm just confused .. and assume the beta DB might be too.

--- **EDIT** --------------------------

Meanwhile I've logged out of all StackExchange sites and tried to re-register. No can do, my opendid (user lexu on tex.stackechange.com ) is somehow associated with qbi's account here on meta or his with mine.

The mixup also makes meta.tex.stackexchange act very strangely:

- I can't logout, this logs me out of tex.stackexchange instead,
- I can't seem to see portions of the site
- I can't see the preview of this message I'm editing
- I can't login from my iPAD (all system type links from meta.tex.stackexchange.com seem to perform their functions on tex.stackechange.com

-- **EDIT 2** ---------------------

This is in reply to reemrevnivek's answer, I cannot add a comment to his answer, as stated above.

When I follow the link you provide I get qbi's user page ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/201/ ) on text.stackexchange. Thankfully I cannot edit it! My user on that page is https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/209/lexu, I seem to have registered some time after qbi... somehow my openid gives me limited access to this (qbi) account

And no, it's not mine (I'm lexu, not qbi), it's qbi's! I wouldn't edit it on tex.stackexchange.com even if I could, I feel bad enough stepping on his feet here in meta, by editing this message under his alias .. but I cannot seem to fix the links. My goal is to be able to work on meta as 'lexu.

**LATER:** Editing my (lexu) profile on tex.stackoverflow.com results in a

```
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
    * unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your user page on the parent site (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/201/ for you). At the top of your profile, it should show something like:

```
Registered User         **edit** | add openid
name            reemrevnivek
member for    4 days
```

You should be able to change your username by clicking the 'edit' option.

This will also change your meta user profile.  Your meta and parent user profiles are identical. This is in spite of the fact that information about questions, answers, and comments for the meta or parent page are only shown on their respective user pages.   Reputation is shared on both sites.

If this does not work, then this deserves the 'bug' tag.  If this behavior is not what you expect, perhaps it should be better documented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't understand your bug report at all. I have read it three times, and I still am unclear what is happening, or if anything is still wrong.

Can you clear all your domain cookies and try again?

Comment: The bug report says that user `lexu` (id 209, who posted the above question) seems to get logged in and displayed as `qbi` (id 201, who is another user).

Comment: I'll clear the cookies and give it a go. ('lexu)

Comment: I've been able to repeat it. Will report in email how.

Comment: Aren't you going to give any interesting details about what was wrong???

Comment: @samb this was an error on stackexchange.com AFAIK, it had to do with the code there and not on the actual sites.