# This SE Site Can't Identify Me

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My email address is soonhui.ngu@gmail.com, and my [SO profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3834/ngu-soon-hui) here. But I am identified as [user972](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/972/user972) here at Tex SE site!! I think something went wrong with the account association when I first registered my email with this site.

**Edit: The reason why my display name is now synch with SO profile is because I manually changed the display name. However, other information were not changed manually, as you can see by comparing the two links above.**

Comment: Your [profile on the main site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/972) is correct and will probably sync to meta soon. Just give the database some time.

Comment: @Caramdir, it's because I manually change my display name to synch with other SE sites. However other infos are not synch manually-- for example, my website.

Comment: Closed to avoid it popping up again via the community user.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. SO or SX is confused, as you guessed: try clearing all your account associations on your pages both here and on SO, and seeing which the sites can find.  Then add them back again.
2. Is it possible you used a different Openid provider to your other accounts?  If so, I don't think you will be able to associate them, but you will be able to create a new account that can be associated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're not the first to experience this here. Take a look at this discussion:

[User Table scrambled?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/user-table-scrambled)

Comment: That one talks about an account that was created and went missing, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Caramdir's comment is correct.  Can you take a look at your profiles again now and see if there's anything still wrong?  I'm seeing the same information here, at the main site, and at SO.

---

Okay, the names fooled me.  Apologies.

There's not a lot that I can see to do from this end as we have no access to the SO user account stuff.  Are you absolutely sure that you used the same openid on both systems?  If you used a different one on SO, try setting up a new account here with the same openid as the SO and then I (or one of the other mods) can merge them.  Or, as the account here hasn't done anything yet, I can delete or destroy it (not sure what the difference is) and you can start again and see if it works.

But if it needs anything that actually involves SO then you need to mention this on meta.SO.  We only have access to our user tables, so can't force an association with an SO account (at least, as far as I can see from the tools.  The only one that I don't understand that might help is "clear sessions" but as I don't know what it does, I'm reluctant to try in case it's dire.).

Comment: I think I just leave this case for the time being. It is just a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

We no longer infer usernames from OpenID URL strings.

This was a bad idea and had a number of long term negative effects, such as, nobody could reply to you because you had no real username.