# Why do I see questions answered, when I chooses "Unanswered"?

Tags: discussion

When I select the "Unanswered" group I get a lot of questions that have one or more answers. For example [Is displaying comments disabled?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/is-displaying-comments-disabled) is answered last month.

What is the meaning of "Unanswered"?

Answer (score 8):

'Unanswered' means that the question has no upvoted answers. You can see this "definition" in the side bar, after you click 'unanswered'.